# Объединить циклы и вынести за if

Tags: python, simple-draw

```
import simple_draw as sd

# Нарисовать стену из кирпичей. Размер кирпича - 100х50
# Использовать вложенные циклы for
width = 100
height = 50
y = 0
y1 = height
for i in range(12):
    start_point = sd.get_point(0, y)
    end_point = sd.get_point(600, y)
    sd.line(start_point, end_point, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=3)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        x1 = 0
        x2 = 0
        # TODO вот эти циклы можно было бы объединить в один, вынеся его за if
        for _ in range(7):
            start_point = sd.get_point(x1, y)
            end_point = sd.get_point(x2, y + y1)
            sd.line(start_point, end_point, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=3)
            x1 += width
            x2 += width
    else:
        x1 = width/2
        x2 = width/2
        for _ in range(6):
            start_point = sd.get_point(x1, y)
            end_point = sd.get_point(x2, y + y1)
            sd.line(start_point, end_point, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=3)
            x1 += width
            x2 += width
    y += height
```

Код рабочий, все отлично. Пытаюсь вынести в один, x1 и x2 не определяется тогда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if i % 2 == 0:
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 0
else:
    x1 = width/2
    x2 = width/2

for _ in range(7):
    start_point = sd.get_point(x1, y)
    end_point = sd.get_point(x2, y + y1)
    sd.line(start_point, end_point, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=3)
    x1 += width
    x2 += width

y += height
```

В вашем коде для разных веток `if` разное количество итераций (6 и 7) - я сделал одинаково, чтобы упросить код (на результат визуально не повлияет, просто некоторые вертикальные палки будут рисоваться за границами окна).